# How to run recursive queries with sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

Here is the thing.
I have this query:

```
const usersManagedByMe = await users.findAll( 
                            { include: [ 
                                { model: classic_users, where: { manager_id:  classicUserIds}, include:[ 
                                    { model: workgroups, where: { id: workGroupIds} } 
                                ] } 
                            ], where: { enabled: true} } );
```

What is happening is that if I find a someone I managed I will need to also check if this user manage someone else and the same at least for 10 levels.

Do you know if there is a way to do this in Sequelize? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include all associated models, you can use the `all` and `nested` options:

```js
// Fetch all models associated with User
User.findAll({ include: { all: true }});

// Fetch all models associated with User and their nested associations (recursively)
User.findAll({ include: { all: true, nested: true }});
```

[Documentation - Including everything](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html#including-everything)